# DateTime with Azure and a JavaScript application

Tags: javascript, c#, date, azure, datetime

I hate Dates.

So, in my JavaScript application I pass the current date to my c# Web API.
I do it as I would expect you to do it like this:

```
var model = {
    plannedCollectionDate: new Date()
};
```

In my c# Web API I save that directly to the database.
Then when I have this bit that tries to create a summary page.
It does something like this:

```
// If we have some collections
if (collections != null && collections.Count > 0)
{

    // Get our collections
    due = collections.Where(m => m.PlannedCollectionDate.Date < DateTime.Today).ToList();
    today = collections.Where(m => m.PlannedCollectionDate.Date == DateTime.Today).ToList();
    expected = collections.Where(m => m.PlannedCollectionDate.Date == DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).Date).ToList();
    planned = collections.Where(m => m.PlannedCollectionDate.Date > DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).Date).ToList();
}
```

The problem is, azure is set to the US timezone and my application is running from the UK. So all the dates are not correct and therefore the due, today, expected and planned are all wrong.

What I need to do is make sure that all the dates are using the same timezone.
I tried just storing the date part of the DateTime when saving to the database by doing

```
model.PlannedCollectionDate = date.Date;
```

but that didn't work either. It's hard to test because I can't step through code when it is running on azure, but before I stored the Date as just the date (i.e. with the time) it was setting everything to 23:00.

What i would like is just a solution I can apply to any project.
If I send a date to my application, it should just convert it to UTC and store it, then whenever I do comparisons it should do UTC comparisons and when I return the Date to the JavaScript application it should know to display it as the local date time.

Can anyone help me?

## Update

Let me break it down a bit more. I have a **CollectionRequestModel** Which looks like this:

```
public class CollectionRequestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue)]
    public int CenterId { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CustomerReference { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerBusinessName { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime PlannedCollectionDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public CollectionStatusRequestModel Status { get; set; }

    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DeliveredDate { get; set; }
    public string ReceivedBy { get; set; }
    public string ReceivedBySignature { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CollectedDate { get; set; }
    public string CollectedBy { get; set; }
    public string CollectedBySignature { get; set; }
}
```

This is created by invoking a method on my web api that looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates or updates the collection
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">The collection which is to be saved</param>
/// <returns>The collection that was saved to the database</returns>
private async Task<IHttpActionResult> SaveAsync(CollectionRequestModel model)
{

    // If our ModelState is invalid, return a bad request
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    // Update our CreatedById
    model.CreatedById = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    // Create a holder for our collection
    var collection = new Web.Models.Collection();

    // If our model has an id
    if (model.Id > 0)
    {

        // Update our collection
        collection = await UpdateCollectionFromModelAsync(model);
    }
    else
    {

        // Create our collection
        collection = ModelFactory.Create(model);
    }

    // Save the changes
    this.service.Save(collection);

    // Save to our database
    await this.UnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Return the result
    return Ok(this.ModelFactory.Create(collection));
}
```

The ModelFactory and UpdateCollectionFromModel don't refactor the data. The ModeFactory looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a collection model from the binding model
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">The binding model</param>
/// <returns>A collection</returns>
public Web.Models.Collection Create(CollectionRequestModel model)
{

    // Get our current user's id
    var date = DateTime.UtcNow;

    // Assign our binding model to a new model
    var collection = new Web.Models.Collection()
    {
        Id = model.Id,
        CenterId = model.CenterId,

        Reference = model.Reference,
        Description = model.Description,
        CustomerReference = model.CustomerReference,
        CustomerName = model.CustomerName,
        CustomerBusinessName = model.CustomerBusinessName,
        SupplierName = model.SupplierName,
        PlannedCollectionDate = model.PlannedCollectionDate.Date,
        Status = (CollectionStatus)model.Status.Id,

        DeliveredDate = model.DeliveredDate,
        ReceivedBy = model.ReceivedBy,
        ReceivedBySignature = model.ReceivedBySignature,

        CollectedDate = model.CollectedDate,
        CollectedBy = model.CollectedBy,
        CollectedBySignature = model.CollectedBySignature,

        CreatedById = model.CreatedById,
        DateCreated = date,
        ModifiedById = model.CreatedById,
        DateModified = date
    };

    // Return our collection
    return collection;
}
```

As you can see, I just pass the `model.PlannedCollectionDate.Date` without trying to change cultures or setting it as UTC or whatever.
From my JavaScript application I just set the **plannedCollectionDate** as a **new Date('24/08/2016')**.
If I use my console I can see the date is sent like this:

> Thu Aug 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

When I run that on the azure server, it gets saved into the database as:

> 2016-08-23 00:00:00.000

which is totally wrong. When I edit locally or on the azure side, they both return the 23rd. So the problem is when sending the date (it seems).
I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Make sure you pass the timezone from the Javascript to the server, and then make sure to use DateTimeOffset, not DateTime in your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this a different way to the suggestions, maybe the wrong way but it appears to be working.

I created an extension method:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the date from the server time to the UK time
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dateTime">The datetime object to convert</param>
    /// <param name="timeZoneId">The timezone to convert to</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DateTimeOffset ToZoneTime(this DateTime dateTime, string timeZoneId = "GMT Standard Time")
    {          

        // Get the timezones
        var currentTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
        var targetTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);

        // Convert the supplied date into the new timezone specific date
        var actualDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTime, currentTimeZone, targetTimeZone);

        // Return our converted dateTime
        return actualDate;
    }
}
```

and when I create or update anything, I do this:

```
// Assign our binding model to a new model
var collection = new Web.Models.Collection()
{
    PlannedCollectionDate = model.PlannedCollectionDate.ToZoneTime().Date
};
```

Comment: The only problem that I can see with this is that now the server decides that all times coming from clients are in GMT.

Comment: is that an issue? I mean if I were in japan when the dates are served back to me, wouldn't they be in my local time?

Comment: If you access it in Japan, new Date() will give you the local time there. Then your server adjusts it as if it was in GMT.

Comment: Of course dates that are already correct there will be shown correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the date in strict ISO8601 format:

```
String s = myDate.ToString("s"); // example 2009-06-15T13:45:30
```

You can then parse it into a date

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,"s", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: what are you saying? Any date I send to my API I need to convert to a string?

Comment: well you don't show / tell us how you are doing that so I presumed you are calling a url with querystring parameters?

Comment: Note that the example does not include the time zone, so will be treated as local (i.e. per the time zone offset setting of the host) when parsed. That may wall exacerbate the OP's issues.

Answer (score 0):

This belongs as a comment to Matt Wilko's answer, but I don't have the rep.

Pass the date from your JavaScript code in ISO format:

```
var model = {
    plannedCollectionDate: new Date().toISOString()
};
```

Save the date in you database as is.

When you are doing your comparisons, I would recommend using DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime, but that is for a different discussion.

Finally, pass the date to your client in ISO time. You client code should be responsible for translating it into the correct timezone.

```
var someISOFormattedDate = getDateFromWebAPI();
var localDate = new Date(someISOFormattedDate );
```